# How do I solve this trig integral?

Tags: integration, trigonometric-integrals

How do I solve this trig integral?

$$I=\int \frac{1+\cos x}{\sin x}\:dx$$
Is there any trig identity that I can use?

Comment: Are you allowed to use standard integrals for $\cot$ and $\csc$? If yes then just split the integrand into two.

Comment: You don't "solve" an integral.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution

Answer (score 7):

Multiply top and bottom by $1-\cos x$ to get $\int \frac{\sin x}{1-\cos x} \; dx.$
Then $u=\cos x$ does the job.

Comment: I would pick $u = 1-\cos x$ and the integral comes out to $\ln(1 - \cos x)$. Clever substitution, +1

Answer (score 3):

$1 + \cos x = 2 \cos^2(x/2)$

$\sin x = 2\sin(x/2)\cos(x/2)$

Substitute these to get $\int \cot(x/2) dx $ .

Substitute $\sin(x/2) = t, \,$ so $\;\cos(x/2)dx =2dt $ and proceed.

Answer (score 0):

The method provided by @B.Goddard is really simple and succinct. Here is another method if you know the standard integrals of trigonometric functions $\implies$

Just split the fraction inside the integral sign as

> $$\int \frac {1+\cos(x)}{\sin(x)} dx = \int \left({\frac {1}{\sin(x)} + {\frac {\cos(x)}{\sin (x)}}}\right)  dx$$
>
> $$=\int \csc(x) + \int \cot(x) dx $$
>
> $$=-\ln\Big|\csc(x) + \cot(x)\Big| + \ln\Big|\sin(x)\Big| + C$$

To avoid confusion, I will do the next steps in a little bit detail :

> $$=-\left(\ln\Big|\csc(x)+\cot(x)\Big|-\ln\Big|\sin(x)\Big|\right) + C$$
>
> $$=-\ln  \left|{\frac {\csc(x) + \cot(x)}{\sin(x)}}\right| + C$$
>
> $$=-\ln \left|{\frac {\csc(x)}{\sin(x)}} + {\frac {\cot(x)}{\sin(x)}}\right| + C$$
>
> $$=-\ln\left|{\frac{1}{\sin^{2}(x)}} + \frac {\cos(x)}{\sin^2(x)}\right| + C$$
>
> $$=-\ln\left|\frac{1+\cos(x)}{\sin^2(x)}\right|+C$$
>
> $$=\ln\left|\frac {\sin^2(x)}{1+\cos(x)}\right| + C$$
>
> $$=\ln\left|\frac {1-\cos^2(x)}{1+\cos(x)}\right|+C$$
>
> $$=\ln\left|\frac {\big(1-\cos(x)\big)\big(1+\cos(x)\big)} { \big(1+\cos(x)\big)}\right| + C$$
>
> $$=\ln\Big|1-\cos(x)\Big|+ C$$

Hope this makes sense to you... :)

Just take care of the negative signs(pun intended).....

**EDIT :** Although the method seems long and tedious, it just employs the standard integrals of trig functions and the logarithm manipulation required to simplify everything does not take much time and is easy$\Big($at least for me :-) $\Big)$. I have taken the annoying negative sign out so as to make simplification easier to see and understand, but not factoring out a $-1$ still works fine.

Comment: It'll be way much easier if you multiply the integrand by $\frac{\sin x}{\sin x}$ then let $u=1-\cos x$

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova秀 Thats similar to the methods used above .... i have just provided a different approach so as to help future readers.